# aspnet core 6 REST API Large File Upload getting Status 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to upload file file with file size around 134MB via Postman.
I'm getting Status: 413 Request Entity Too Large.
I've added FormOptions attributes at Startup class too.

Could anyone advise how to solve that issue?

[image: upload-file]
[image: postman-upload-file-call]
[image: FormOptions-config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your case `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` is conflicting with `[RequestSizeLimit(500*1024*1024)]`.

Just these options do the trick:

[image]

[image]

I didn't use the authorize attribute as mine was only a test app.